# how to split name into first and last name in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table that contain first name and last name as below

`First_Name   LAST_NAME`

```
John       Milano
Garry      Sanders 
           Barr, Jerome P
           Venti, Louis
```

I need to correct some rows which has complete name in the column Last_name. My desired output is:-

`First_Name   LAST_NAME`

```
John       Milano
Garry      Sanders 
Jerome     Barr
Louis      Venti
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure you prevent recurrence before fixing existing records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you close, with a couple caveats:  1) Some first names have two words -- "Mary Ann", etc.  So, you probably want to keep those.  2) You only want to change rows where the LAST_NAME column contains a comma.

```
UPDATE MyTable
    SET First_Name = LTRIM(SUBSTRING(LAST_NAME, CHARINDEX(',', LAST_NAME) + 1, 100)),
        LAST_NAME = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@name, 0, CHARINDEX(',', @name))))
WHERE CHARINDEX(',', LAST_NAME) > 0
```

So, you will have "Jerome P" as the first name still.  If you want to restrict first names to a single word, you would have to do a bit more.  This should work:

```
UPDATE MyTable
    SET First_Name = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@name, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', @name))))
WHERE CHARINDEX(' ', First_Name) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a case expression with `CHARINDEX` and `LEFT`

```
select
    First_Name 
    ,case
         when charindex(',',LAST_NAME) > 1 then left(LAST_NAME,charindex(',',LAST_NAME) - 1)
         else LAST_NAME
     end as LAST_NAME
From YourTable
```

**Example**

```
declare @var varchar(64) = 'Barr, Jerome P'

select 
case
    when charindex(',',@var) > 1 then left(@var,charindex(',',@var) - 1)
    else @var
end
```